# HTTP URL Rewriting Modifier doesn't catch attribute

Tags: jmeter

I use HTTP URL Rewriting Modifier.  First I send request get request. Response data is XML format.  Second I send request with HTTP URL Rewriting Modifier. I added attribute in XML file to HTTP URL Rewriting Modifier but it doesn't catch the attribute. How to catch attribute HTTP URL Rewriting Modifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier is based on [regular expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) and [tries to find the parameter value](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/src/protocol/http/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/modifier/URLRewritingModifier.java#L150) like:

```
name="attribute-name-you-give" value="attribute-value-you-re-looking-for"
```

if the structure of your XML response is different and the node you're looking for doesn't have both `name` and `value` attributes - it will find nothing.

Most probably a better idea would be going for [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/xpath-extractor-jmeter) instead

Comment: thank you a lot Dmitri T. Regular Expression Extractor is too useful. Also I have a question. Does HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier support JSON response data.